# Add sub-routine for Office.js Javascript Word add-in using asynchronous execution context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, office-js

I have had a lot of success dipping my toes into developing an Office.js add-in for Word. One of the common tasks of the add-in is searching and replacing, which needs to be used by multiple action buttons in the add-in. Therefore I'd like to create a function that separates out together the search and replace task so I can avoid errors and make the code more modular. I am getting stuck in attempting to do this with the Office.js asynchronous execution model.

This code works (as a method to a React class):

```
    replaceX() {
    console.log("replaceX");
    window.Word.run(async (context: any) => {

        const range = context.document.getSelection();

        await context.sync();
        var query = "X";
        var replacement = "gabagool";

        var results = range.search(query);
        results.load();               

        await context.sync();

        for (var i=0; i<results.items.length; i++) {
            results.items[i].insertText(replacement,'Replace');
        }

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

But this code fails:

```
    replaceX() {
    console.log("replaceX");
    window.Word.run(async (context: any) => {

        const range = context.document.getSelection();

        await context.sync();
        var query = "X";
        var replacement = "gabagool";

        this.replaceInRange(context, range, query, replacement, {});

        await context.sync();
    });
}

async replaceInRange(context:any, range:any, query:String, replacement:String, searchOptions:any) {
    console.log('replaceInRange');
    var results = range.search(query, searchOptions);
    results.load();
    await context.sync();

    for (var i=0; i<results.items.length; i++) {
        results.items[i].insertText(replacement,'Replace');
    }

}
```

I've tried a few variations but I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental. Can anyone help me figure out the right way to handle a subroutine that needs to access the context of the parent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is breaking the Promise chain. Your `replaceInRange` method has an async call within it to `context.sync`, but `replaceInRange` is not itself awaited, so as soon as it starts to execute, the execution engine moves on to the line below the call to `replaceInRange`, which is another `context.sync`. But this last `context.sync` will complete, and then the `Word.run` will complete, before the string replacement code runs.

Try putting an `await` keyword in front of the call to `replaceInRange` like this:

```
await this.replaceInRange(context, range, query, replacement, {});
```

A couple of other things I noticed:

1. The very first `context.sync` in your `Word.run` is not needed.
2. You aren't passing any parameters to the `load()` method. When you do this, all scalar properties are loaded. This is an unnecessary performance hit. You only need to load the `text` property to do an `insertText`. Use `results.load('text');`
3. `Word.run` is itself asynchronous, so you should probably use the `await` keyword when you call it. You can get away without not having `await` because your parent method calls nothing after the Word.run executes, but if you ever modified the method so that something more is called after `Word.run`, that something more would start executing before the `Word.run` was complete if you don't await the `Word.run`.

There's a good book about Office add-ins that has lots of information about these subjects, including Promise chains: [Building Office Add-ins](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins). It cost something but it's worth it. Before you ask, it's not my book and I don't gain anything from its sales.

Comment: Thanks, I will think about buying that book--it does look good. I tried adding the `await` keyword and making the other changes you suggested, as well as adding more logging statements. The rest of the function actually doesn't seem to execute at all, with or without the `await` before replaceinrange.

Actually, I added a dummy method like this:     dummy() {
        console.log('running dummy');
    }

And even if I run it before the replaceInRange function, nothing is logged from the function. This is very confusing.

Comment: @Quinten Your code worked for me when I put the await in front of the call to replaceInRange (and removed the "this" from the front of it). I would speculate that there's something about how you are calling replaceX() and/or how you are using the "this" keyword that are causing you problems, but I can't see enough of the context of your code to be more precise.

Comment: Removing it as a method of the class and making it an independent function works...good enough for me. Thank you so much for your help. I'll have to read up more on this, as this my first foray into asynchronous land.

Comment: @Quinten, one other thing I would recommend is to make sure that you either return the `Word.run` promise or await it -- and make sure that somewhere upstream of it, you are using either a `try/catch` (if using `await`) or are doing a `.catch` (promise-based).  I find that having proper error-handling from the start takes a lot of guesswork out of what is going on (though of course, only if you are properly chaining/awaiting promises and are not breaking the Promise chain -- otherwise you can still get infuriatingly silent errors).